# How to pass this function upon button click

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am trying to create this program so that when you click the button 1 it will run the function firstClass. Not quite sure why it isn't working.

HTML:

```
  <form onSubmit="return firstClass();">

  <h1>Click "1" for first class seats. Click "2" for economy class seats</h1>

     <button type="submit">1</button>
  </form>
```

Javascript:

```
 var seatArray = [ , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
 var first = 1;
 var economy = 6;

        function firstClass()
        {               
           if (first <= 5 && seatArray == 0) 
           {    
              window.alert("You have chosen First Class. You have been given seat number: ");
           }
           else
           {
              window.alert("Seats are full");
           }
           return false;
        }
```

Comment: Regardless of your HTML code, jQuery code would be $(document).ready(function() { $('#myForm').on('submit', firstClass); });

Comment: Define "isn't working". What do you expect to happen? How does this differ from what actually happens?

Answer (score 2):

Your function get`s called. Only made the method global, because fiddle runs it in another scope.

```
 var seatArray = [ , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
 var first = 1;
 var economy = 6;

    window.firstClass = function()
    {               
       if (first <= 5 && seatArray == 0) 
       {    
          window.alert("You have chosen First Class. You have been given seat number: ");
       }
       else
       {
          window.alert("Seats are full");
       }
       return false;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fvAAG/